# Is it possible to configure Spring Data JPA to save entities in FIFO mode?

Tags: save, spring-data-jpa, fifo

I'm wondering if there is any way to make Spring Data JPA JPARepository.save() method delete the oldest entry and save the new one (FIFO).
I don't want to implement it manually and then figure out that Spring Data is already able of doing it itself.
Thank you.

Comment: what is the backend you are using?

Comment: @KarthikPrasad what do you mean ? 
I actually think I found a way but now I'm struggling with converting my composed SQL to HQL to be understood by my JPARepository..